# how to ignore .com .net or .org from text that made of sentences end with period, escalation or question mark into array of sentences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried `'abc.com setence 1. sentence2?sentence3.com. sentence 4 something here!'.match(/.*?[?!.(?!com | net| org)]/g)`

but get `(56) ["abc", ".", "c", "o", "m", " ", "se", "t", "e", "n", "c", "e", " ", "1.", " ", "se", "n", "t", "e", "n", "c", "e", "2?", "se", "n", "t", "e", "n", "c", "e", "3.", "c", "o", "m", ".", " ", "se", "n", "t", "e", "n", "c", "e", " ", "4 ", "so", "m", "e", "t", "hin", "g", " ", "he", "r", "e", "!"]`

what I wanted to get is something like
`['abc.com sentence1.','sentence2?','sentence3.com.', 'sentence 4 something here!'`]

I think I place the `(?!com | net| org)` wrong meant to ignore these 3 domain from the period recognization when break down sentences.... but not sure the right way to fix it...

Comment: 'abc.com setence 1. sentence2. sentence3.com.'.split('. ');

Comment: @Randy Casburn sorry my example over simplify the dividers.. modified!

Comment: then it appears there is not a repeatable pattern - Regex won't work. You'll need to parse the string manually.

Comment: what is your actual string or sentance and what is the expected output? I don't see your actual string in the question

Comment: @NishanthMatha this: `'abc.com setence 1. sentence2?sentence3.com.'` just prior to match. OP is using a literal string.

Comment: @NishanthMatha actual its an article lol I just simplified it with some example of case I encountered

Comment: @Ezeewei so you want to extract all the strings which ends with `.com` or `.org` or similar from the article?

Comment: @NishanthMatha - this: **what I wanted to get is something like ['abc.com sentence1.','sentence2?','sentence3.com.',]** directly from the question

Comment: @NishanthMatha ok, I update the example, so its reflect my intent with more detail... no I am just trying to break sentences down but without considering the `.` before domains as a sentence break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule will split by `.` but exclude any occurrence of `.` followed by com, net, or org. Additionally, it'll split by `?` or `!`. Finally, some array methods are used to clean up the results and make sure the punctuation is retained.

```js
const str = 'abc.com setence 1. sentence2?sentence3.com. sentence 4 something here!';
var splits = str.split(/(\.(?!com|net|org)|\?|!)/i);
var final = [];

splits = splits
  .map(el => el.trim())
  .filter(el => el !== '');

for (let i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
  splits[i] += splits[i+1];
  splits.splice(i + 1, 1);
}

console.log(splits);
```

Comment: I would say it's more base on that 3 symbols rather than space to be more accurate! Thanks for asking

Comment: @Ezeewei okay, can you check the update out? I think this might do what you need!

Comment: By the way, in regular expressions `.` is a metacharacter meaning any single character will match. You need to escape it with `\\`!

Comment: boy its super close, but it also remove the spliting character which I actually want to keep.... also I modified the sample and result a bit to be more tough to reflect more closer to reality but not too long! thank you so much for working with this fun challenge!

Comment: Okay okay, took another shot. Let me know!

Comment: woooooooowwwww, this is awesome! Thanks @Nick! It seems works really really well!

Comment: Woohoo! Was fun, glad I could help @Ezeewei